# Form input to build string of object calls on submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I am building a form where the values will build an array of calls to an object. The object call generates an image URL using the thumbor image processing service.

**Goal: Build an `$obj -> methodOne() -> methodTwo();` query using a html form and output the response with ajax.**

A typical **PHP Object Call** would look like this:

```
echo $thumbnailUrlFactory
    -> url('http://example.com/image.jpg')
    -> fitIn('500', '400')
    -> addFilter('Brightness', '70')
    -> smartCrop('True');
```

The output would look something like:
`http://myserver.com/SECURITY_HASH_STRING/500x400/filters:brightness(70)/smart/http://example.com/image.jpg`

**HTML FORM**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="image_url"> <!-- Value: http://example.com/image.jpg -->
    <input type="text" name="fit_in"> <!-- Value: '500', '200' -->
    <input type="text" name="filters['brightness']['value']"> <!-- Value: 70 -->
    <input type="text" name="filters['contrast']['value']"> <!-- Value: 40 -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The important thing to note is there is roughly 30 different filters and 8 different crop types. I cannot just build a php call that calls every possible option as it would override some other calls.

My form will display the URL and fit in input fields on load.
I then have a button to add additional pairs of fields: one 'filter name' and one 'filter value'.

What is the best way to approach this??

Comment: so if you want to use the values from the submitted form to make your command it would be something like `echo $thumbnailUrlFactory
    -> url($_POST["image_url"])
    -> fitIn($_POST["fit_in_1"], $_POST["fit_in_2"])
    -> addFilter($_POST["filter_name"], $_POST["filter_value"])
    -> smartCrop($_POST["smart_crop"]);` (this uses slightly different names from the ones in your example form, which don't quite work, it seems). Of course, you'd want to validate all the inputs before passing them to your methods directly, but hopefully this gives you the idea.

Comment: You're correct - however, assume the `brightness` variable is empty. This would leave `/filters:brightness()/` in the URL string. So it needs to incorporate an `if` statement. If brightness is set, add the appropriate method call. Currently, `if` will produce a 500 error if used before a call.

Comment: that's where the process of validating your data before making the call comes into play. If that's not an acceptable situation, stop the execution and return an error to the user asking them to complete all the required fields.

Comment: But the point is, there are 8 different crop types. So a user could specify `resizeTo -> (x,y)` rather than `fitIn -> (x,y)`. It is not a requirement to enter all the different options and filters. They are just there to be used if needed.

Comment: then you perhaps need a more generic call like `->crop("resizeTo", "500", "300")` which can accept all the various crop types. Just like your "addFilter" example. Of course if some of these are entirely optional, then you'll have to split your final call up into lots of optional calls rather than one line of code chaining them all together. e.g. you do `$url = $thumbnailUrlFactory->url($url); if ($_POST["cropType"] != null) { $url = $url->crop(...` etc.

Comment: Sorted - I didn't actually know you could append additional methods by splitting it up in this way.

Comment: yeah that syntax is called method chaining, it's just a shorthand. Each of the methods returns the whole object as the output, which is why you can then immediately call another method joined on to it and appear to operate on the original object. You actually operate on the return value of the previous method in the chain, which happens to be a reference to the original object. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining Very trendy way of writing code right now, but it's certainly not essential to do it all in a single line like that.

Comment: Thanks for the help! i'm glad I now know this :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: split the methods up rather than in one string. I didn't know we could do this until today.

The syntax is called **Method Chaining**

```
<?php
$image = $thumbnailUrlFactory -> url ( $_POST['url'] );

if (!is_null($_POST['fitIn'])) {
    $image = $image -> fitIn ( $_POST['fitIn'] );
}

if (!is_null($_POST['smart'])) {
    $image = $image -> smartCrop ('true');
} etc...
```

effectively, this builds:

```
$image = $obj;
$image = $image->methodOne();
$image = $image->methodTwo();
$image = $image->methodThree();
$image = $image->methodFour();
etc...
```